# How to Determine Independence in a two die roll scenario?

Tags: probability, dice

Assume event 1: we roll a 4 first, event 2: we roll a sum of 10.

The P(Event 1) = 1/6.

The P(Event 2) = 3/36 or 1/12. (3 ways out of 36 possibilities for 2 rolls to sum to 10).

To determine if events are independent, we need to check $P(A\cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$.

So $P(Event 1 \cap Event 2) = 1/36 $ (only one way to roll a 4 first and get a sum of 10 out of 36 possibilities). Then $P(Event 1) \cdot P(Event 2) \neq 1/12$, so these events are dependent.

Is this logic correct or did I miss something?

Comment: Logic is correct.

Comment: Naturally if the second roll was rolled after the first one, using the same die, it is completely dependent on the first roll.  Its the memory of the die.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to end with

> Then $P(Event 1) \cdot P(Event 2) = \frac16 \cdot \frac1{12} = \frac{1}{72}\not= \frac1{36} = P(Event 1 \cap Event 2)$ so these events are dependent.